# extract text from html tags

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I Want to get countries names only not the initials, how can i go about it
here is the html code

```
<div class="item_country cell small-4 medium-2 large-2">
<img class="theme-flat" src="/AD/flat/64.png"/>
<p class="mb0 bold">AD</p>
<p>Andorra</p>
</div>, <div class="item_country cell small-4 medium-2 large-2">
<img class="theme-flat" src="/AE/flat/64.png"/>
<p class="mb0 bold">AE</p>
<p>United Arab Emirates</p>
```

I am getting :

```
AD
Andorra

AE
United Arab Emirates
```

instead of:

```
Andorra
United Arab Emirates
```

here is my python code

```
page = requests.get('https://www.countryflags.io')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all(class_="item_country cell small-4 medium-2 large-2")
for table in tables:
    country= table.get_text()
    print(country)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS selector `.item_country p:nth-of-type(2)`: that will select second `<p>` tag under tag with `class="item_country"`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_text = '''<div class="item_country cell small-4 medium-2 large-2">
<img class="theme-flat" src="/AD/flat/64.png"/>
<p class="mb0 bold">AD</p>
<p>Andorra</p>
</div>, <div class="item_country cell small-4 medium-2 large-2">
<img class="theme-flat" src="/AE/flat/64.png"/>
<p class="mb0 bold">AE</p>
<p>United Arab Emirates</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

for p in soup.select('.item_country p:nth-of-type(2)'):
    print(p.text)
```

Prints:

```
Andorra
United Arab Emirates
```

---

If you prefer standard bs4 API:

```
countries = soup.find_all('div', class_="item_country cell small-4 medium-2 large-2")
for c in countries:
    print(c.find('p', class_="").text)
```